# YARN compression codecs with Apache Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm running Apache Spark (1.3.0) on YARN. The `YARN_CONF_DIR` points to the YARN configuration. `core-site.xml` is loaded from that directory. It includes a setting for `io.compression.codecs`, and this list includes `com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec`, which is not included in the pre-built Spark.

This causes a `ClassNotFoundException` on startup. As a workaround we can run with a modified `core-site.xml` or we could include the required Jar file with `--jars`.

Neither of these workarounds are very robust. I am not the administrator of the YARN cluster. The cluster administrator can make changes to `core-site.xml` without my knowing. If I'm using a modified copy, I will miss out on important changes. If I'm using `--jars`, my Spark application will break when a new codec is added.

Are these codecs stored in a standard place? How could I add that place to my classpath? I'd like my application to survive config changes without anything to do on my part.

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer is to include all Hadoop jars, something like this:

```
--jars $HADOOP_HOME/../hadoop-yarn/lib/*.jar
```

My problems with this are:

- I'm not sure how standard this path is.
- This will cause the jars to be copied to the workers each time the application is started. I expect when a codec is deployed its jar is put on all the YARN nodes, or at least it's put on HDFS in a shared location. There must be a better way to access it!

Comment: This is what I do. I haven't found a way around that!